# I can't get my locally stored variable value in my Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am spending hours trying to figure out what's so wrong with my code.
The details are as below.
It seems like after my form validation in test.ts it's hard to access the local value stored initially.

> test.html

```
     ...
    <form [formGroup]="AddBankForm">
              ...
    </form>
        <!--step 1 -->
        <button (click)="storeKey('500')">Store It</button>

        <!--step 2 -->
        <button (click)="checkAccountKey()">Check It</button>
      ....
```

> test.ts

```
  @Component({
   selector: 'test',
   templateUrl: 'test.html'
  })
  export class TestPage {

   constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {}

  ....
    //------------------
 public AddBankForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   bank: ["", Validators.required],
   acname: ["", Validators.required],
   acno: ["", Validators.required],
   title: ["", Validators.required]
  });
  ...
  editAccountkey: string;

  storeKey(accountid: string) {

    this.editAccountkey = accountid;
  }

  ....

  checkAccountKey() {

    if (this.AddBankForm.valid) {
    alert("My key is "+ this.editAccountkey);
    }
  }
  ....
 }
```

> my alert() 
>   result = My key is
>   ....but
>   expected result = My key is 500

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a plunker?

Comment: How did you setup your project? Are you testing on an mobile device? (ionic2 tag)
I never used ionic2 but maybe thats why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because you have not initialized `editAccountkey` variable. Default value of `editAccountkey` variable is not defined.

So when you click on first button, then click on second button, it will show proper result. However if you click on second button directly, it will not show any value of `editAccountkey`

In this case you should initialize `editAccountkey` variable like below:

> public editAccountkey: string = '555';

Or you may have assigned it a empty value.

Comment: the buttons are postioned in a way that you must click the 'Store it' button before you click on the 'Check it' button. that is why i commented on them as Step 1 and Step 2.  So the Step 1 initializes the variable.

Comment: You might have updated the value of editAccountkey somewhere else. Or you may have got exception in storeKey function before value assignment of editAccountkey

Comment: I just tried accessing the variable immediately before the 'if' statement and it worked fine. But within the if statement it's just not available

Comment: Oh yeah... i just figured it. i have mistakenly assigned it to an empty string before asking for it. Phew... Thanks greatly.